# "THREE.WebGLRenderer: A WebGL context could not be created. Reason: Failed to create a WebGL2 context" error in Angular Studio

Tags: android, angular, three.js, ionic5

I'm new to Angular-Ionic and I created my first App with THREE js, now. When I run it in Firefox or Chrome, I don't get any erros at all. But when I run it with Android Studio I get a lot of errors.

Examples:
Could not create a WebGL context, VENDOR = 0xffff, DEVICE = 0xffff, GL_VENDOR = Google (NVIDIA Corporation), GL_RENDERER = Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (NVIDIA GeForce MX350/PCIe/SSE2), GL_VERSION = 526.98, Sandboxed = no, Optimus = no, AMD switchable = no, Reset notification strategy = 0x8252, ErrorMessage = bindToCurrentThread failed:

glDrawElements: framebuffer incomplete (check)

Shader Error 1280 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Failed to create a WebGL2 context.

[in Angular Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsSly.png)
[in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvi5W.png)

my home.page.ts (and I know, it's not a clean code):

```
import { Component, ElementRef, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { Water } from 'three/examples/jsm/objects/Water';
import { Sky } from 'three/examples/jsm/objects/Sky';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {
  steps = 1000
  target = 10000
  progress = this.steps / this.target


  @ViewChild('canvas') container!: ElementRef;

  protected scene
  protected camera
  protected renderer
  protected controls
  protected pmremGenerator

  constructor() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(this.renderer)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
    this.container.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, -1000);

    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    this.controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.46;
    this.controls.minDistance = 10.0;
    this.controls.maxDistance = 200.0;
    this.controls.update();
    this.controls.update();
    let sun = new THREE.Vector3();

    const waterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000);

    let water = new Water(
      waterGeometry,
      {
        textureWidth: 1024,
        textureHeight: 1024,
        waterNormals: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../../assets/textures/waternormals.jpg', function (texture) {

          texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

        }),
        sunDirection: new THREE.Vector3(),
        sunColor: 0xffffff,
        waterColor: 0x001e0f,
        distortionScale: 3.7,
        fog: true
      }
    );

    water.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;

    this.scene.add(water);

    const sky = new Sky();
    sky.scale.setScalar(10000);
    this.scene.add(sky);

    const skyUniforms = sky.material.uniforms;

    skyUniforms['turbidity'].value = 5;
    skyUniforms['rayleigh'].value = 0.1;
    skyUniforms['mieCoefficient'].value = 0.006;
    skyUniforms['mieDirectionalG'].value = 0.55;

    let renderTarget;

    let cylinderGeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(50, 50, 10, 100)
    let cylinderMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      metalness: 0,
      roughness: 1
    })
    let cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeo, cylinderMat)
    this.scene.add(cylinder)
    cylinder.position.set(0, -3, 0)
    cylinder.receiveShadow = true

    const loader = new GLTFLoader;
    loader.load(
      'assets/Wohnhaus.glb',
      (object) => {
        this.scene.add(object.scene);
        object.scene.position.set(0, 2, 0)
        object.scene.scale.set(10,10,10)
      }
    )

    


    this.updateSun(sky, water, sun, renderTarget);
    this.animate(water)
  }

  animate(water: Water) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => { this.animate(water) })
    this.controls.update()

    water.material.uniforms['time'].value += 1.0 / 60.0;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  updateSun(sky: Sky, water: Water, sun: THREE.Vector3, renderTarget: any) {

    const parameters = {
      elevation: 10,
      azimuth: 90
    };

    const phi = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(90 - parameters.elevation);
    const theta = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(parameters.azimuth);

    sun.setFromSphericalCoords(1, phi, theta);

    sky.material.uniforms['sunPosition'].value.copy(sun);
    water.material.uniforms['sunDirection'].value.copy(sun).normalize();
    sky.castShadow = true
    water.castShadow = true

    if (renderTarget !== undefined) renderTarget.dispose();

    renderTarget = this.pmremGenerator.fromScene(this.scene);

    this.scene.environment = renderTarget.texture;

  }
}
```

I already tried different Android Versions and Phones and I always have the same problems.

**Update**
I have changed WEBGLRenderer to WEBGL1Renderer. In my Code I removed the commented code. Now I don't get any Errors at all. I can see the cylinder now, but not the GLTFModel.

```
let cylinderGeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(50, 50, 10, 100)
    /*let cylinderMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      metalness: 0,
      roughness: 1
    })*/
    let cylinder = new THREE.Mesh(cylinderGeo)
    this.scene.add(cylinder)
    cylinder.position.set(0, -3, 0)

    const loader = new GLTFLoader;
    loader.load(
      'assets/Wohnhaus.glb',
      (object) => {
        this.scene.add(object.scene);
        object.scene.position.set(0, 2, 0)
        object.scene.scale.set(10, 10, 10)
      }
    )
```

Comment: It seems WebGL 2 isn't properly supported in your environment. Do the errors go away if you use `WebGL1Renderer` instead?

Comment: Try to add an ambient and directional light to your scene. And remove the render target texture from `Scene.environment`. Since your platform does not support WebGL 2, it's possible the device does not support half float textures as well which means you can't use PMREM and HDR workflows.

Comment: Hey, it has been a while. I tried some things and now I figured out, that i have to replace Physical Materials and Mesh Standard Materials with Basic Materials. Now, i don't get errors, but it doesn't look great. Do you have an idea, how i could use Physical Materials anyway or make Basic Materials look like Physical Materials. And thanks for answering, by the way.